# CSS absolute div center

Tags: jquery, css, center, absolute

How do I center an absolute div?

```
<div class="photoWindow">min width 600 px, absolute</div>
```

jQuery

```
var widthScreen = $(window).width();
$('.photoWindow').css({'margin-left': widthScreen / 2 - widthScreen, 'left':'50%'});
```

However, this does not center the div.

Comment: is there a reason why it needs to be `position:absolute`?  specifying a width on the div and using `margin: 0 auto;` centers a div.

Comment: @centr0, This div with a photo should appear on top of everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function centerMe(element) {
    //pass element name to be centered on screen
    var pWidth = jQuery(window).width();
    var pTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop()
    var eWidth = jQuery(element).width()
    jQuery(element).css('top', pTop + 100 + 'px')
    jQuery(element).css('left', parseInt((pWidth / 2) - (eWidth / 2)) + 'px')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").css({marginLeft: (($(window).width() / 2) - ($(this).width() / 2))});
});
```

Comment: What is it? margin-left = 0px

Comment: No this will set the div's `margin-left` to be half the window height minus half of the div's width, meaning it will be centred.

Answer (score 1):

Set margin left and margin right to "auto", that should to the trick.

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

or simply

```
margin: 0 auto;
```